# Are dogs allowed in Lokas like Kailasha and Vaikuntha?

Tags: animals, swarga, vaikuntha, kailasa

It is probably a well-known fact that dogs are **not** allowed in the heaven (Swarga). For e.g. the dog which accompanied Yudhishthira on his way to the heavens was denied entry in there.

The Smritis also say that gods and manes do not accept offerings of those persons who keep dogs.

But, on the other hand, a dog has a clear cut spiritual connection. For example, it is related to Ketu (which is considered as Moksha Karaka-the reason that triggers Moksha/liberation). A black colored dog is also related to Dharma-related deities like Yama and Shani apart from being the Vahana of Lord Bhairava too.

So, obviously dogs are of some spiritual significance and it is allowed in particular in Bhairava Loka.

- I am specifically looking for references which talk about as to whether dogs are allowed in Kailasha and Vaikuntha or not.

Comment: bdw how we r sure that dogs r not allowed in heaven???...bcz that episode was to test Yudhisthir...that dog was not  in reality... similarly they showed Yudhisthir that his brothers r in hell but in fact they were in heaven...so when they said dogs r not allowed, was it to test Yudhisthir's response or a fact?? how we can conclude???

Comment: I hv heard tht dogs are not allowed in heavens. The Smritis also condemn the dogs way too much.. so .... @YDS

Comment: your question a priori assumes there is a difference between different forms of life. The outer sheath is different than the inner sheaths that survive death. All life forms have an individual atma with its own individual karma. The material outer sheath does not survive death. Most atmas that have a dog's birth have not gone through their individual karmas to go to any lokas. So a question of 'allowed' is not valid.

Comment: @Rickross Do they condemn dogs or just state the Devas/gods don't go near them? Because other explanations like fear make sense for that. Maybe there is a prophecy of a dangerous dog that will destroy the heavens. That would also explain why the more powerful deities have no qualms with dogs, as they are too powerful to be in danger.

Comment: Dogs are considered "impure" @AupakaranaAbhibhaa

Comment: @Rickross Where are they considered impure? The only situations I know of either would lead to concluding something else is impure which makes no sense which makes no sense in other mentions or can be explained by the fear of the Devas to be near them. Bhairava is both too powerful and probably not technically a Deva, so he has no reason not to be with dogs.

Comment: @Rickross Imagine if you were a Deva and practically invulnerable to anything else on Earth, but you knew someday, somewhere a legendary dog will be born of devastating power. You will not go anywhere near dogs, because you want to live, regardless of whether or not you like dogs, or whether they are impure.

Comment: A legendary elephant, tiger or horse can be born too and threaten the Devas .. why only dog?@AupakaranaAbhibhaa

Comment: @Rickross I never said they could not. It is just the actions of a Devas, especially the evil Deva (Gandharva) Kali, implies it is a dog that will be their mortal enemy.

Comment: @Rickross There is a legendary horse of devastating power. Harinagara as I explained before is probably the fated avatar of Vishnu to help Kali. He is devastating to us, not the Devas. I'm surprised you did anticipate I would bring him up; I assume you read my posts on the Bhavishya Purana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I don't know about Kailasha, but can answer about Vaikunta)*

No & Yes.

If you had asked "Are **humans** allowed in Vaikunta?", answer would still be No & Yes.

Only those atma which have exhausted all their karma, hence by definition got rid of any prakrita shareera (Bhagavad Gita 'Tyatkva Deham punar janma'), which happens as a consequence of bathing in Viraja, can reach Vaikunta.
Vaikunta is not a even 'meta-physical' loka like svarga, since even svarga is prakritka.

At that point, it is simply atma, hence no difference between dog atma or man atma, because these are only differences of body, not soul.

Whether dog, dog-eater or dog-master, if they exhaust all karma, then yes, then can reach Vaikunta. If not, no.